# Crystal Reports X - Exporting to Excel automatically?

Tags: crystal-reports

"Problem": When doing reports, I have to manually export like 50 reports based on some dates depending on the kind of report (monthly, quarterly).

Question: Is there any way to make this automatic? Like I press a button or run a script that generates the reports on their given dates, then automatically exports this to some folder as an excel file?

Thanks for all your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scheduling tools - Crystal's own scheduling tool for Crystal Reports X was called Crystal Enterprise. They often included this free with Crystal Reports, but only licensed for relatively small numbers of users.

If your company already has Crystal Enterprise and the licensing permits it, I suggest using that. (I'm not sure whether Crystal/BO/whoever they are now will still sell Crystal Enterprise 10; even if they do, the licensing *may* be prohibitively expensive.)

Alternatively, consider third party scheduling tools, or even writing your own.

Comment: It's called "Crystal Reports Server 2008" now, rather than Crystal Enterprise, but this is essentially the same advice I was going to give. Pricey, but it might fit your needs.

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sme/freetrials/index.epx

Comment: I haven't looked at this yet but it seems like from their description...scheduling is what I need. Scheduling can run my reports and export to excel right?

Comment: @Ehsan, it depends on the scheduling tool. Crystal/BO/SAP's own tools should definitely enable it, but you may have to pay significant extra sums for licensing (which is why I recommended checking whether your company already has Crystal Enterprise).

Answer (score 1):

I use R-Tag Report Manager (www.r-tag.com) to schedule my reports. It supports report packages, which can be used to run multiple reports together. I have a similar scenario: to run and deliver 30 reports at the beginning of each month. Instead of running each report separately I packed them and it takes minutes to run them all together by setting the parameters on the package level instead of going through each report

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Visual Cut (http://www.milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT.htm). This little package has a command line interface for generating and exporting .rpt files, including burst reports (i.e. 1 file per level 1 group).  I use this all the time for automation.  If you have several .rpt files you need processed, then you can just put all your command lines into a single batch file and you'll have the 1-button nirvana you seek :)

The author is also very responsive if you get the annual support.  Every single time I've sent him a question, he emails or calls back within the day.